# Attempted to access r(0); index must be a postive integer or logical

Tags: matlab

```
    %ENGR 151 Lab 3 Part 3
clc  
clear  
disp('ENGR 151 Lab 3 Part 3')  
disp('Solid Snake')  
disp(' ')  
r = ones(1,41)  
v = ones(1,41)  

for i = 0:0.5:20  
    r(i) = -.05 + round(i) * .05  
    v(i) = (4/3) * pi * r(i)^3  
end
```

I am a little bit confused. I think what this is saying is that there is no such position in my array that is not a whole number but the directions for this problem specifically state "Plot the volume of a sphere as a function of r for r = 0 to 20 by steps of 0.5 using
a FOR loop. V=(4/3)*pi*R3 . This will require 41 loops. You will need to allocate
memory for the variables r and v. Use the equation r= -0.5 + i* 0.5 to find r given
the loop i. You will need to update the r and v equations from above with
appropriate subscripts to store the r and v in each loop." Why not just make a for loop from 0 - 40 instead of this .5 increment?

Comment: "positive *integer*" should be enough of a clue .. the problem *doesn't* say *use* `i` as an index .. it just explains what values `i` should have for each step ("0 to 20 by steps of 0.5"), how many steps ("41" loops), and the formulae to use ("r given the loop i").

Comment: I was confused because I code in C# and in C# index 0 would be fine. That whole index 0 was throwing me off so much that I could not see that I needed an outside counter to do the job and get around the .5 increments. But Vectorizing my code seems to be better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to populate the vector r, then you can use a counter that is initialized outside of the for loop and increment each loop

```
cnt = 0;
for i = 0:0.5:20
    cnt = cnt + 1; %increment at the beginning so any users of cnt get the 1-indexed value 
    r(cnt) = -.05 + round(i) * .05  
    v(cnt) = (4/3) * pi * r(cnt)^3  
end
```

Comment: Got ya! I didnt know that's what subscript meant and I completely forgot my teacher had said that index's start at 1 and not 0 like in other languages. Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

You might as well vectorize your code:

```
r = -0.05 + round(0:0.5:20) * 0.05;
v = (4/3) * pi * r .^3
```

This will make your code more elegant and you avoid the indexing trouble that you have there.

Comment: Yes, but this doesn't use a `for` loop as required. If used as an answer the `for` answer should still be provided.